# etckeeper implementation in subversion (SVN)

Tags: svn, git, etckeeper

How to setup etckeeper in subversion (SVN).I get to know that etckeeper works with git , mercurial (hg) etc, but it  doesn't works with subversion.

I am stuck with this etckeeper implementation in svn...

Any further help.....

Comment: Is it compulsory to use `etckeeper`? How about the `fsvs`?

Comment: You are "stuck with" this implementation -- Did someone already hack `etckeeper` and you have an existing deployment using svn? Or are you considering a new deployment?

Comment: As my firm is using svn,  I am unable to shift to git.Ok let me try fsvs and will let you know .

Answer (score 4):

[From the project's website:](http://joey.kitenet.net/code/etckeeper/) `etckeeper is a collection of tools to let /etc be stored in a git, mercurial, darcs, or bzr repository.`

So as far as "supported" solutions go: You can't do this. (I also can't fathom why you'd want to -- IMHO git and Mercurial are far superior to SVN).

If you're really interested you can dig through the `etckeeper` source code and add in the support, but deploying git would seem to be a less painful solution.

Comment: can you suggest some other tools like etckeeper which works with svn , any idea? thanks

Comment: hello any further help???

Answer (score 1):

git client has SVN server support. I never test it. Probably on older GIT client version you may have problems with https and password less authorization to svn server.
you can learn this doc:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-and-Subversion

At first try to make a connection from git client to svn server separately, outside to etckeeper. If it isn't possible, show some svn repository without authengication (if you have) and encryption (plain http). If you'll success, make the same using crypting tunnel.
If you'll all win, try to move configuration to etc git repository.